# I'm not able to run the MVN goals through shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I just used the below shell script in Post Build activity in JENKINS "Execute Shell" cmd

```
 #!/bin/bash
 mvn --version
 export M2_HOME=/opt/maven/maven-3.3.3 # your Mavan home path
 export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
 mvn --version
 echo $HOME
 echo $WORKSPACE

 file=$WORKSPACE/XXXX/XXXX-reports
 cd $file

 cp XXXX-1.html test.html

 fail=`grep "test-method.*FAIL" results.xml | sed -e 's/^.*test- 
 instance-name="\(.*\) ' | tr '\n' ','`
 echo $fail

 count=0

 while [ $count -lt 5 ]
 do
 if [ ! -z "$fail" -a  "$fail" != " " ];

 then

 echo `$M2_HOME/bin/mvn clean test -f ../../pom.xml -DInclude=${fail}`
 cp XXXX-report.html ReReport_$count.html

 retry=`expr $count + 1`

 fi
 done
```

In the above shell script I'm trying to run the mvn command and continuing to run 5 times to increase pass count in UNIT script execution.

But It's not working. It's failed to execute the maven goals. So, I just comment the executable and added echo to debug.
But no luck.

Any leads

Comment: Are there any error messages when you try to execute the maven commands?  Maybe you could send those to a log file somewhere, and examine that afterwards.

Comment: You have a syntax error: `exit  0"`

Comment: (Tip: https://www.shellcheck.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use this following script that modifies yours. Add your parameters there.
The product log file: mvn_jenkins.log will allow you to easily find problems as suggested by mjuarez:

```
#!/bin/bash
MVNCMD=$(command -v mvn)
MVNPARAMS=" -version" # replace with your appropriate params
LOGFILE="mvn_jenkins.log"
COUNT=0
while [ $COUNT -lt 5 ]; do
 echo "Execute: $MVNCMD $MVNPARAMS" >> $LOGFILE
 echo "-------" >> $LOGFILE
 $MVNCMD $MVNPARAMS 2>&1>> $LOGFILE
 echo "" >> $LOGFILE
 COUNT=$((COUNT + 1))
done
```

Explanation:

**MVNCMD=$(command -v mvn)**: put the full qualified name of maven execute file in MVNCMD var

**$MVNCMD $MVNPARAMS 2>&1>> $LOGFILE**: Execute mvn command with parameters and redirect error output messages (2) and regular output messages (1) to the log file.

About your maven parameters I don't understand why you use **-DskipTests=true**.

Comment: Can you please give me what this line will do  $MVNCMD $MVNPARAMS 2>&1>> $LOGFILE

Comment: Sorry for miss explanation. I edited my response to add more informations.